# Match 3D world coordinates with 2D image coordinates

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision

There is a set of 3D coordinates of points on the object, in the coordinate system of the object itself (front left bottom/top, front right bottom/top, left/right, rear lift/right). It is need to match the from stereo images between these points of the object and their projections on the image. That is, that point found in the image is a projection of the front left bottom point of the object, etc. I know internal and external parameters of the camera and rotation of the object in its own coordinate system. What are the common solutions to such problems, or everything is based only on heuristics? Just getting acquainted with computer vision, I need any help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is this for `python` or `C++`?

Comment: This may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

Comment: OpenCV, `solvePnP`, if you have the point correspondences. if you don't, the problem may be intractable.

Comment: @christoph-rackwitz Yes, I don't have a correspondence between 2D and 3D points.